# Reference entries on a table via a column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, reference

I have two tables an table A and a table B
Where I for Table B wants to add a column that references entries within table A

Meaning that row one i table B for that particular column respond row on in table A and etc.

tables are created as such

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.a
    (a_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.a_registration 
(
    a_id bigint REFERENCES a(a_id),
    a_row_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    valid tsrange,
    registration tsrange,
    registration_by varchar(255),
    name text
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.b
    (b_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.b_registration 
(
    b_id bigint REFERENCES b(b_id),
    b_row_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    valid tsrange,
    registration tsrange,
    registration_by varchar(255),
    person text
);
```

the way I add the column ref which is supposed to contain a foreign key to the table A entries i do this.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_attribute
               WHERE  attrelid = 'public.b_registration'::regclass  -- table name here 
               AND    attname = 'ref'    -- column name here
               AND    NOT attisdropped
              ) THEN

        ALTER TABLE public.b_registration 
        ADD COLUMN ref Serial references a_registration NULL;
ELSE
        ALTER TABLE public.b_registration
        ALTER COLUMN  ref  TYPE Serial references a_registration;
END IF;
END
$$;
```

gives me an error something about syntax error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REFERENCES"
LINE 14:      ALTER COLUMN  ref TYPE  SERIAL REFERENCES s...
```

but that will never be triggered, but the true statement never triggers since it states there is is

I get this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SERIAL"
LINE 11:   ADD COLUMN ref b_row_id SERIAL REFE...
```

Comment: Please post the complete DDL for both tables. BTW the alter statement you did post does not create a reference from table_b to table_a it creates a recursive relationship in table_b referring to another row in table_b.

Comment: @Belayer added a full example